# How to improve the CPU efficiency on running deep learning model

Tags: python, deep-learning, cpu, keras

I am running a baseline model, with the overall architecture `Conv3D->MaxPooling->Conv3D->MaxPooling->Softmax`. I have approximate 1000 training samples, with individual dimension `(x, y, z, channel) = (64, 64, 32, 1)`. The total number of the training parameters of my baseline model is 258,561. Before using GPU acceleration, I wanna see how long it is going to take to finish training by CPU. I am using Keras, the backend is Tensorflow. I have 32 CPUs in my work station, here is the efficiency of all CPUs:

[image]

Is there some way to improve the efficiency? Clearly there are many CPU idle resources to be utilized. Thank you!

Comment: Which `os` do you have? How have you installed your `keras`?

Comment: Try running it on the GPU?

Comment: The `os` is ubuntu `14.04 LTS`.  I haven't installed cuDNN and CUDA on my work station. I am pretty new to GPU. I thought my work station has enough computing power to do a baseline model running. However, it obviously cannot use all my resources.

Comment: @Marcin Możejko I did install 'keras' in `Ubuntu 14.04LTS`.

Comment: Try installing `mkl` by e.g. installing `anaconda` which has it as a default package.

Comment: Maybe the CPU capacity is not limiting, perhaps the read/write to memory speed is.

Comment: @Marcin Możejko. I did use `anaconda`, so I do have `mkl` installed.

Comment: @ roganjosh Is there any way to find out whether read/write to memory speed is limiting the computing? Thank you.

Comment: I don't actually know how to check that exactly, but for sure there will be some intermediate storage in your CPU cache and RAM. We'll both be looking for the answer I guess!